# Python 3: Checking next value of an iterator without iterating

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, for-loop, iterator

For a project I need to check in a csv file if the value in a certain column of the next row is equal to the value in the same column of the current row. I am using a dictionary csv reader, i.e. each row in the reader is a dictionary file. I can access a value of a certain row by using the column header as a key: `row[header] = value`.

A stripped-down version of my current code looks like this:

```
import csv

with open(os.path.abspath(path_to_file), "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')

    for row in reader:
        current_row = row
        next_row = reader.__next__()
        if current_row[column] == next_row[column]:
            dosomething()
```

The problem here is of course that I skip the next iteration by using `__next__()`, i.e.

(1) I enter the loop; row = row1
(2) current_row = row1, next_row = row2
(3) I enter the next iteration of the loop; row = row3 because I used `__next__()`. current_row = row3, next_row = row4

In this example I would never check `row2 == row3`.

Is it possible to check the values of the next row without iterating over the iterator object?
Or, alternatively, is there an opposite methode to `__next__()`, which makes the iterator go back one step?

**Please note**: I'm comparing the *current* value to the next *value* instead of the *current* value to the *last* value because I don't know how long the file I'm reading is. I have to treat the last row of the file different from the others, so I have to check `reader.__next()__` anyway to see if there is a last line at all.

Comment: How can I read the last row with a `csv.reader` without reading all the other rows before it though? I would have to iterate twice through all elements of the iterator in the end. That, or I misunderstood you.

Comment: The 'last'/'previous' row is the row that was just read (before the last next'ing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `itertools` `pairwise` recipe. A more general solution is to `tee` your iterator (which is what the pairwise recipe uses). Another possibility is to create a function that has a cur and next variable and yields the values you want (basically what pairwise does, but you could make this yield the fields in your CSV rather than entire rows).

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

```
def pairwise(iterable):
     "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

I think pairwise does everything you need here, so no fussing with your own generator function or `tee`.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')

for current_row, next_row in pairwise(reader):
    if current_row[column] == next_row[column]:
        dosomething()
```

Realize that if you have an iterable with `n` items, there will be `n-1` items in pairwise.

Comment: I don't understand a couple of things in your solution.

First of all, in Python 3 there's no `itertools.izip` method, I have to use `itertools.zip` instead. That does not seem to be a problem in this case though.

`next(b, None)` should return a `None` object for `next_row` when `current_row` is the last item in the reader. If I iterate through a reader with `pairwise(reader)` and print `current_row` and `next_row` in each step, the loop stops when it reaches the tuple (second last row, last row), but I **need** to check in the for-loop whether the next row is the last one in reader though.

Comment: Just replace izip with map

Comment: I don't know how map could be of any use here. Anyways, I used the proposed ```pairwise``` function and just made some adjustments to check the last row of reader _outside_ of the loop. Now I have some lines of sort of duplicate code, but everything works as intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your requirements conflict with idea of built-in iterator. So I suggest you encapsulate your cycling inside custom iterator.
Idea is to yield two values from original iterator having None for the next value of last row.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would look back, instead of looking ahead, assuming the constraints of your scenario allow it:

```
it = iter(reader)
prev_row = it.next()
while True:
    try:
        cur_row = it.next()
        if cur_row[column] == prev_row[column]:
            dosomething()
        prev_row = cur_row
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if this might work but it works in android

```
reader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')
  reader2 = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel')

  for row in reader:
    current_row = row

        for row2 in reader2
          next_row = reader2.__next__()
          if current_row[column] == next_row[column]:
          dosomething()
          continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Because dictionaries must retain unique keys (so cannot append rows with same keys) and `csv.DictReader` object is not subscriptable (so cannot reference column or row number), consider reading csv data into a **list** and then compare row to subsequent row:

```
import csv

with open(os.path.abspath(path_to_file), "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)

# APPEND READER LINES INTO LIST    
csvList = []
for row in reader:
    csvList.append(row)

# ITERATE THROUGH LIST, CHECK AGAINST NEXT ROW
for i in range(len(csvList) - 1):
    # FIND THE COLUMN NUMBER (BELOW USES 1)
    if (csvList[i][1] == csvList[i + 1][1]):
        doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

(sy,None) or (sy,"") would be the only logical possibilities for the last tuple because the values are popped from a queue one at a time until end of iter.

"Once tee() has made a split, the original iterable should not be used anywhere else; otherwise, the iterable could get advanced without the tee objects being informed."